# How can I customise horizontal menu prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to edit the prestashop module (Top horizontal menu v1.3) I have some categories setup so I have Parent>Child, Child on the menu. I would like to disable the link on the parent category so that it does not link to a page only the child categories link to pages.

Thx for the help.

Comment: You should probably add a prestashop tag to target the right people to answer this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Prestashop, but thought I would provide some sort of feedback anyway.

As a rule of thumb, whenever I'm making a parent>child navigation I like to make the parent link to a [parent] landing page, or if possible a request to the same page on the server which modifies the navigation output on the server side.  This way, if a client has Javascript disabled, or if there is ever a bug in your Javascript, it does not render your navigation useless.

Might be something to think about.  I don't think any item in a navigation should not link to somewhere.

Sorry I couldn't provide any specific help regarding Prestashop.